# Sizing UITextVIew and UITableViewCell to fit to Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView in a (static) UITableviewCell. The textView is empty. What I want is the textView to resize dynamically. Meaning as the user enters some text inside, I want the textView to size to its content.

Next I want the cell to dynamically size to the textview's content.

I called textViewFitToContent in textView shouldChangeTextInRange.

My Problem is nothing works. I tried using just the textViewFitToContent in another project (without the uitableview) and it worked as expected.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (textView == myTextView)
    {
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        {
            [self insertXEveryNewLine:range :textView :@"\n\u2022 "];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)insertXEveryNewLine:(NSRange)place :(UITextView *)View :(NSString *)something
{
    NSRange cursor = NSMakeRange(place.location + 3, 0);
    NSMutableString *mutableT = [NSMutableString stringWithString:View.text];
    [mutableT insertString:something atIndex:place.location];
    [View setText:mutableT];
    [View setSelectedRange:cursor];
    [self textViewFitToContent:View];
    return NO;
}

- (void)textViewFitToContent:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    NSString *text = txtSymtoms.text;
    CGFloat height = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil].size.height;
    return height + 5;
}
```

I'm a begginer, so please don't be too harsh on me.

Thanx

**Update**

I deleted the heightForRowAtIndexPath because I have auto layout, and when I add a new line, nothing happens?

Comment: static cell doest need a datasource (not sure). so if you want to change your cell size dynamically , maybe you should use dynamic prototypes

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the UITableView's Cell height. Which would need to be base off the UitextViews height.

Comment: Can you show me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it please?/

Comment: I'm having some trouble because I need to constraint the textview to the bottom of the cell so something is wrong there, can you help me with that

Comment: So you're using auto layout? If so.. then why are you manually calculating cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Your'e probably right. So I took away heightForRowAtIndexPath, and the textView is not changing its height at all. Whenever I create a new line, nothing happens